# Ignore Column data while importing to MySQL via Command Line

Tags: mysql

This question may sound like a novice one.

I'm having a data table in Mysql like below (ID is autoincrement)

```
 ID   NAME   MDATE   QTY
```

I'm using to load this table from a text file via Command line like

"LOAD LOCAL DATA INFILE....".

It works perfectly. Now in my input text file i've  another new column,that i dont want to import.Like below case, i want to exclude the Count column.

```
Count Name  Date       Qty
1     ABC   1/12/2013  25 
2     ACE   1/12/2013  15 
3     DBC   1/12/2013  12
```

How do i ignore this column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also discard an input value by assigning it to a user variable and not assigning the variable to a table column:

LOAD DATA INFILE 'file.txt'
INTO TABLE t1 (column1, @dummy, column2, @dummy, column3);

Try checking: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html